# проверить, является ли значение required

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

```js
let products = {
  "v1_model-cust": [{
    "id": 13,
    "required": false,
  }],

  "v1_model-update-1": [{
    "id": 14,
    "required": true,
  }]
}
```

Есть объект `products`. Нужно проверить, является ли хоть одно значение `required = true`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ещё вариант:

```js
let products = {
  "v1_model-cust": [
    {
      "id": 13,
      "required": false,
    }
  ],
  "v1_model-update-1": [
    {
      "id": 14,
      "required": true,
    }
  ]
};

const isSomeRequired = Object.values(products).some(
  models => models.some(model => model.required)
);

console.log(isSomeRequired);
```

Answer (score 3):

Решение, не зависящее от структуры :)

```js
const products = {
  "v1_model-cust": [{
    "id": 13, "required": false,
  }],
  "v1_model-update-1": [{
    "id": 14, "required": true,
  }]
};

const anyRequired = JSON.stringify(products)
  .includes('"required":true');

console.log(anyRequired);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let products = {
  "v1_model-cust":
[
  {"id":13,
  "required":false,
  }
],
  
  "v1_model-update-1":[
      {"id":14,
        "required": true,
  }
  ]
}

const values = Object.values(products);

values.forEach(val => val.forEach(key => key.required === true? console.log(key): false ));
```